# How can I disable excel formula autofill?

Tags: excel, autofill

Sometimes, when I enter in a value into a cell in an excel cell, the cells in the adjacent column(s) will automatically populate with the formula of the cell above them.

Here is a test case which causes the behavior. Attempting to enter in a value in cell A5 will autofill the formula into cell B5. Note: This does not occur with 3 or less rows.

```
     A   B
1    0   =A1
2    0   =A2
3    0   =A3
4    0   =A4
5
```

I have already taken the steps on this page (disable formula autocorrect), to no avail: http://www.k2e.com/tech-update/tips/823-tips-disabling-formula-replication-excel-tables

1. Is there any way to stfop this from happening?
2. Can this behavior be disabled on a workbook/user/computer level
   so I never have to deal with it again?

EDIT: Here is a gif of the behavior, to better explain: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tOHXg.jpg

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry for the self-answer, but I was annoyed by this issue again, so I went through the options in excel one by one, disabling them until I found the option that was causing this.

The option is called `Extend data range formats and formulas`, located in `Options > Advanced > Editing options`

Comment: does this work across machines? If I handed this excel to another person, would it also be disabled for them or is this per machine?

Answer (score 5):

Try: 
`Application.AutoCorrect.AutoFillFormulasInLists = False`

Answer (score 0):

Per [the tip](http://www.k2e.com/tech-update/tips/823-tips-disabling-formula-replication-excel-tables), The feature can disable by going to File > Options > Proofing > AutoCorrect Options > AutoFormat As You Type > Uncheck Fill formulas in tables to create calculated columns > Click OK.

[image: Disable Excel table AutoFill formula in AutoCorrect Options > AutoFormat As You Type]